# Example sqlldr to parse Apache common log

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

My searches for complex sqlldr parsing of key-value pairs was thin. So posting an example that worked for my needs that you may be able to adapt.

The issue: millions of lines of Tomcat access log e.g.

```
time='[01/Jan/2001:00:00:03 +0000]' srcip='192.168.0.1' localip='10.0.0.1' referer='-' url='/limsM/SamplesGet-SampleMaster?samplefilters=%5B%22parent_sample%20%3D%208504571%22%2C%22status%20%3D%20'D'%22%5D&depthfilters=%5B%22scale_id%20%3D%2011311%22%5D' servername='yo.yo.dyne.org' rspms='218' rspbytes='2198'
```

are to be parsed into this Oracle table for convenience of analysis of selected parameters.

```
create table transfer.loganal (
   time date
 , timestr varchar2(30)
 , srcip varchar2(75)
 , localip varchar2(15)
 , referer clob
 , uri clob
 , servername varchar2(50)
 , rspms number
 , rspbytes number
 , logsource varchar2(50)
);
```

What does a sqlldr control script look like that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first working solution. Refinements, suggestions, improvements always welcome.

Given Tomcat access log in a directory, e.g.

```
yoyotomcat/
   combined.20010101
   combined.20010102
   ...
```

This file saved as combined.ctl as a sibling of yoyotomcat

```
-- Load an Apache common log format
-- essentially key-value pairs
-- example line of source data
-- time='[01/Jan/2001:00:00:03 +0000]' srcip='192.168.0.1' localip='10.0.0.1' referer='-' url='/limsM/SamplesGet-SampleMaster?samplefilters=%5B%22parent_sample%20%3D%208504571%22%2C%22status%20%3D%20'D'%22%5D&depthfilters=%5B%22scale_id%20%3D%2011311%22%5D' servername='yo.yo.dyne.org' rspms='218' rspbytes='2198'
--
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'yoyodyne/combined.2001*' "STR '\n'"
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE transfer.loganal
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    time enclosed by "time='[" and "+0000]' " "to_date(:time, 'dd/Mon/yyyy:hh24:mi:ss')"
  , srcip enclosed by "srcip='" and "' "
  , localip enclosed by "localip='" and "' "
  , referer char(10000) enclosed by "referer='" and "' "
  , uri char(10000) enclosed by "url='" and "' "
  , servername enclosed by "servername='" and "' "
  , rspms enclosed by "rspms='" and "' " "decode(:rspms, '-', null, to_number(:rspms))"
  , rspbytes enclosed by "rspbytes='" and "'" "decode(:rspbytes, '-', null, to_number(:rspbytes))"
  , logsource "'munchausen'"
)
```

Load the hypothetical example content by running this from a command prompt

```
sqlldr userid=buckaroo@banzai direct=true control=combined.ctl
```

Your mileage may vary. I'm on Oracle 12. There may be features used here that are relatively new. Not sure.

Illumination

- This variant of the "enclosed by" functionality works well for key-value pairs. Its not regular expression, but is performant.
- The ability to treat the column name as a bind variable and apply available SQL functions to it enables much additional flexibility.
- Have some log that has really long GETs, thus the specification of unreasonably long string values. 255 as a default wasn't enough.
- Rspms and rspbytes sometimes had '-'. Used SQL to work around frequent "not a number" errors.
- The control file as written presumes all fields are present. Not a good assumption over time. Looking for config to allow null column when a  enclosure is not matched.

Cheers.